# How to get string name for QEvent in PyQt5

Tags: enums, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2, repr

Under PyQt I'm timing Qt Events and I want to write a human readable string name with the time. With PySide2 just calling `str()` gives me the the string name but with PyQt5 it returns a string that's the enum value:

```
# PySide2
>>> str(QEvent.KeyPress)
'PySide2.QtCore.QEvent.Type.KeyPress'

# PyQt5
>>> str(QEvent.KeyPress)
'6'
```

Is there a way to get the string name using PyQt5? I can post a solution building a lookup table on startup, that works, but wondering if there is a direct way.

Comment: >>> PyQt5.QtCore.QEvent.Type.KeyPress
6
>>> str(PyQt5.QtCore.QEvent.Type.KeyPress)
'6'
>>> QEvent.KeyPress
6
>>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for `PyQt5` and `PySide2`. I'm just create a dict by enumerating every event type in the `QEvent` object. I was hoping for something more built-in though.

```
class EventTypes:
    """Stores a string name for each event type.

    With PySide2 str() on the event type gives a nice string name,
    but with PyQt5 it does not. So this method works with both systems.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """Create mapping for all known event types."""
        self.string_name = {}
        for name in vars(QEvent):
            attribute = getattr(QEvent, name)
            if type(attribute) == QEvent.Type:
                self.string_name[attribute] = name

    def as_string(self, event: QEvent.Type) -> str:
        """Return the string name for this event."""
        try:
            return self.string_name[event]
        except KeyError:
            return f"UnknownEvent:{event}"


# Example Usage
event_str = EventTypes().as_string(QEvent.UpdateRequest)
assert event_str == "UpdateRequest"
```

Comment: so does your solution solve your question:" Is there a way to get the string name using PyQt5? I can post a solution building a lookup table on startup, that works, but wondering if there is a direct way.". I mean PySide is better because of the direct method ?

Comment: This solves the problem. I'll accept it nothing better comes along. But yes the ideal solution would be a way to get a string name from a QEvent.Type in PyQt5. In PySide2 it's easy but in PyQt5 I do not currently see a way to do it. Seems like kind of a big omission, and seems like it's a general question about Enums really.

Comment: I lost you on the Enums bit. I'll google about it. Thanks

Comment: I just mean `type(QEvent.Type)` is `<class 'sip.enumtype'>`. So it's some type of C++ enum exposed through sip. An enum meaning something like `APPLE=1, BANANA=2`. With PySide it seems to expose the string names, but with PyQt5 it doesn't. I'm just saying this is probably an issue with all enums not just event types. But that also means if there **is** a way to get strings with PyQt5, then you can probably use it with **all** enum types not just events types.

Comment: I accepted this since no other answers. But it'd still be nice to know a more automatic way to get the symbolic names for enum values under PyQt5.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did to log the events happening on my QWidget subclass. Just made the lookup table from the docs https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html

```
def event(self, event: QtCore.QEvent) -> bool:
    print(event_lookup[str(event.type())])
    return super().event(event)
```

```
event_lookup = {"0": "QEvent::None",
                "114": "QEvent::ActionAdded",
                "113": "QEvent::ActionChanged",
                "115": "QEvent::ActionRemoved",
                "99": "QEvent::ActivationChange",
                "121": "QEvent::ApplicationActivate",
                "122": "QEvent::ApplicationDeactivate",
                "36": "QEvent::ApplicationFontChange",
                "37": "QEvent::ApplicationLayoutDirectionChange",
                "38": "QEvent::ApplicationPaletteChange",
                "214": "QEvent::ApplicationStateChange",
                "35": "QEvent::ApplicationWindowIconChange",
                "68": "QEvent::ChildAdded",
                "69": "QEvent::ChildPolished",
                "71": "QEvent::ChildRemoved",
                "40": "QEvent::Clipboard",
                "19": "QEvent::Close",
                "200": "QEvent::CloseSoftwareInputPanel",
                "178": "QEvent::ContentsRectChange",
                "82": "QEvent::ContextMenu",
                "183": "QEvent::CursorChange",
                "52": "QEvent::DeferredDelete",
                "60": "QEvent::DragEnter",
                "62": "QEvent::DragLeave",
                "61": "QEvent::DragMove",
                "63": "QEvent::Drop",
                "170": "QEvent::DynamicPropertyChange",
                "98": "QEvent::EnabledChange",
                "10": "QEvent::Enter",
                "150": "QEvent::EnterEditFocus",
                "124": "QEvent::EnterWhatsThisMode",
                "206": "QEvent::Expose",
                "116": "QEvent::FileOpen",
                "8": "QEvent::FocusIn",
                "9": "QEvent::FocusOut",
                "23": "QEvent::FocusAboutToChange",
                "97": "QEvent::FontChange",
                "198": "QEvent::Gesture",
                "202": "QEvent::GestureOverride",
                "188": "QEvent::GrabKeyboard",
                "186": "QEvent::GrabMouse",
                "159": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneContextMenu",
                "164": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneDragEnter",
                "166": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneDragLeave",
                "165": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneDragMove",
                "167": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneDrop",
                "163": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneHelp",
                "160": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneHoverEnter",
                "162": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneHoverLeave",
                "161": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneHoverMove",
                "158": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseDoubleClick",
                "155": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove",
                "156": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress",
                "157": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseRelease",
                "182": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneMove",
                "181": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneResize",
                "168": "QEvent::GraphicsSceneWheel",
                "18": "QEvent::Hide",
                "27": "QEvent::HideToParent",
                "127": "QEvent::HoverEnter",
                "128": "QEvent::HoverLeave",
                "129": "QEvent::HoverMove",
                "96": "QEvent::IconDrag",
                "101": "QEvent::IconTextChange",
                "83": "QEvent::InputMethod",
                "207": "QEvent::InputMethodQuery",
                "169": "QEvent::KeyboardLayoutChange",
                "6": "QEvent::KeyPress",
                "7": "QEvent::KeyRelease",
                "89": "QEvent::LanguageChange",
                "90": "QEvent::LayoutDirectionChange",
                "76": "QEvent::LayoutRequest",
                "11": "QEvent::Leave",
                "151": "QEvent::LeaveEditFocus",
                "125": "QEvent::LeaveWhatsThisMode",
                "88": "QEvent::LocaleChange",
                "176": "QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonDblClick",
                "174": "QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress",
                "175": "QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease",
                "173": "QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseMove",
                "177": "QEvent::MacSizeChange",
                "43": "QEvent::MetaCall",
                "102": "QEvent::ModifiedChange",
                "4": "QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick",
                "2": "QEvent::MouseButtonPress",
                "3": "QEvent::MouseButtonRelease",
                "5": "QEvent::MouseMove",
                "109": "QEvent::MouseTrackingChange",
                "13": "QEvent::Move",
                "197": "QEvent::NativeGesture",
                "208": "QEvent::OrientationChange",
                "12": "QEvent::Paint",
                "39": "QEvent::PaletteChange",
                "131": "QEvent::ParentAboutToChange",
                "21": "QEvent::ParentChange",
                "212": "QEvent::PlatformPanel",
                "217": "QEvent::PlatformSurface",
                "75": "QEvent::Polish",
                "74": "QEvent::PolishRequest",
                "123": "QEvent::QueryWhatsThis",
                "106": "QEvent::ReadOnlyChange",
                "199": "QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel",
                "14": "QEvent::Resize",
                "204": "QEvent::ScrollPrepare",
                "205": "QEvent::Scroll",
                "117": "QEvent::Shortcut",
                "51": "QEvent::ShortcutOverride",
                "17": "QEvent::Show",
                "26": "QEvent::ShowToParent",
                "50": "QEvent::SockAct",
                "192": "QEvent::StateMachineSignal",
                "193": "QEvent::StateMachineWrapped",
                "112": "QEvent::StatusTip",
                "100": "QEvent::StyleChange",
                "87": "QEvent::TabletMove",
                "92": "QEvent::TabletPress",
                "93": "QEvent::TabletRelease",
                "171": "QEvent::TabletEnterProximity",
                "172": "QEvent::TabletLeaveProximity",
                "219": "QEvent::TabletTrackingChange",
                "22": "QEvent::ThreadChange",
                "1": "QEvent::Timer",
                "120": "QEvent::ToolBarChange",
                "110": "QEvent::ToolTip",
                "184": "QEvent::ToolTipChange",
                "194": "QEvent::TouchBegin",
                "209": "QEvent::TouchCancel",
                "196": "QEvent::TouchEnd",
                "195": "QEvent::TouchUpdate",
                "189": "QEvent::UngrabKeyboard",
                "187": "QEvent::UngrabMouse",
                "78": "QEvent::UpdateLater",
                "77": "QEvent::UpdateRequest",
                "111": "QEvent::WhatsThis",
                "118": "QEvent::WhatsThisClicked",
                "31": "QEvent::Wheel",
                "132": "QEvent::WinEventAct",
                "24": "QEvent::WindowActivate",
                "103": "QEvent::WindowBlocked",
                "25": "QEvent::WindowDeactivate",
                "34": "QEvent::WindowIconChange",
                "105": "QEvent::WindowStateChange",
                "33": "QEvent::WindowTitleChange",
                "104": "QEvent::WindowUnblocked",
                "203": "QEvent::WinIdChange",
                "126": "QEvent::ZOrderChange", }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> type(QEvent.KeyPress)
<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QEvent.Type'>
>>>
```

PyQt5 doesn t give name:

```
>>> PyQt5.QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Type' object has no attribute 'name'
>>>
```

PySide2 does:

```
>>> (PySide2.QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress.name)
b'KeyPress'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
print(QEvent.Type(event.type()).name)
```

Comment: Please elaborate your solution.